# AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtCore' has no attribute 'DisplayRole'/my friend run it fine but not me, Is anyone know how can I fix these error?

Tags: python, pyqt5

It's some thing like this

```py
from msilib import add_data
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
class pandasModel(QtCore):
    
    def __init__(self, data):
        QtCore.__init__(self)
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parnet=None):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == QtCore.DisplayRole:
                return str(self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])
        return None

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role ):
        if orientation == QtCore.Horizontal and role == QtCore.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[col]
        return None
```

Comment: Typo: it's `QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole` (the `ItemDataRole` enum is part of the [`Qt` Namespace](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html)). I don't know why it works on your friend's computer, but it shouldn't, unless they used odd/unorthodox import statements

Answer (score 3):

Seems that the more recent version of PyQt have changed where DisplayRole, etc. live.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

...

def headerData(self, col, orientation, role ):
    if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
        ...
```